# iteration difference using map in C++

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to solve the [Isomorphic Strings](https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/) problem in leetcode.

I come to the following code, the question is that the commented block should function as same as the uncommented iteration, but it fails to return right answers. However, the current code can pass the tests. Why the difference? Thanks.

"aa""ab" should return false.

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isIsomorphic(string s, string t) {

    if(s.size() != t.size())
        return false;

    map<char, int> ms;
    map<char, int> mt;

/*  for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ms[s[i]] != mt[t[i]])
           return false;
        else
            ms[s[i]] = mt[t[i]] = i;
    }
*/      

    int n = s.size();
    int i = n;

    for (; i >= 0 ; --i) {
        if (ms[s[n-i]] != mt[t[n-i]])/*|| s[i] == t[i]*/
            return false;
        else
            ms[s[n-i]] = mt[t[n-i]] = i;
    }
    return true;
} 
};
```

Comment: Looks exactly the same to me. Ideone agrees: http://ideone.com/dBVA5V

Comment: try "aa" "ab" . thanks.

Comment: What do you think `map[key]` is if the key isn't in the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mapped_type& operator[] (const key_type& k);
>   **Access element**
>
> If k matches the key of an element in the container, the function
>   returns a reference to its mapped value.
>
> If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the
>   function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference
>   to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container
>   size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the
>   element is constructed using its default constructor).

Note: default construction of an integer sets it to zero.

Let us apply this logic to s="aa" and t="ab" in your commented part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ms[s[i]] != mt[t[i]])
           return false;
        else
            ms[s[i]] = mt[t[i]] = i;
    }
```

i = 0: both maps are empty, so we insert ms['a'] = 0 and mt['a'] = 0, and comparison says they are equals. then they are both set to i, which is: 0

i = 1: ms['a'] is found already set previously to 0, and mt['b'] not found but inserted = 0. but equality succeeds, and then both are set to 1.

loop ends, with success.

What was the problem: if at step 2 we found ms[a] at a different value, the test would not succeed.

Solution: dont use zero as a value in the map. use any value, such as i+10.

```
ms[s[i]] = mt[t[i]] = i + 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first (commented out) for loop will loop `s.size()` times (from 0 to `s.size()-1` inclusive).

Your second for loop will loop `s.size() + 1` times (from `s.size()` to 0 inclusive).

Edit: This isn't why you are failing the tests, but it is a difference between the two.

The reason you are failing the tests is as @T.C. said - map[key] returns 0 (in your case) if the map doesn't contain the character, but you are using 0 as the value for the first letter found. So your code can't tell the difference between the first letter and a not found letter.

The reason your second loop works is that the `i` you are using isn't 0 (except in the last, invalid, iteration), so you don't get the collision between the first letter and not found.

A simple solution is to use

```
ms[s[i]] = mt[t[i]] = i+1;
```

in your first loop

Comment: It does not make much difference.